# Аналог PtrToStructure для классов

Tags: c#, указатели, память

Товарищи, стал мне интересен следующий вопрос:

Положим, есть у нас примера ради структура `System.Drawing.Point`
Мы спокойно можем баловаться с ней следующим образом:

```
// Инициализируем нашу структурку
Point point = new Point(2, 3);

// Получаем ее адрес
Point* pointer = &point;

// Получим ее данные
int x = ((int*)pointer)[0]; // 2
int y = ((int*)pointer)[1]; // 3

// Получаем ту же структуру, разыменовав указатель
Point copied = *pointer;

// Или так (получаем нулевую `Point` по указателю)
copied = pointer[0];

// Или даже так
copied = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Point>(new IntPtr(pointer));
```

В общем, имея указатель, мы спокойно можем получить **структуру** в явном виде

---

Теперь же отойдем от *типов значения* и перейдем к типам *ссылочным*, то есть поговорить я хочу о подобных механизмах для **классов**

Оперируя инстансами классов, мы на деле оперируем их ссылками, то есть, получив указатель, мы получим указатель на ссылку на определенный участок памяти, где как раз и можно найти данные объекта

То есть следующий псевдо-код:

```
// Обозначим instance'ы классов
MyClass my0 = new MyClass { A = 2 };
MyClass my1 = new MyClass { A = 3 };

// Некоторые действия
IntPtr* ptr0 = ...;
IntPtr* ptr1 = ...;

IntPtr tmp = *ptr0;

ptr0[0] = ptr1[0];
ptr1[0] = tmp;

Console.WriteLine(my0.A); // 3
Console.WriteLine(my1.A); // 2
```

На деле аналогичен простой смене переменных местами

---

И вот теперь главный вопрос: каким образом, имея указатель, я могу также, как и в случае со структурой, получить объект?

Проблема в том, что

- Создание указателя на класс - невозможно (ошибка [CS0208](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0208))
- А [Marshal.PtrToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) также рассчитан только на структуры

То есть я ищу нечто такое:

```
IntPtr* pointer = ...;
// Я знаю, что это не работает, это просто псевдо-код
MyClass my = *((MyClass*)pointer);
my = Marshal.PtrToClass<MyClass>(new IntPtr(pointer));
```

---

Собственно, **возможно ли** такое в `C#` (не думаю, что прямо совсем никак) и, если да, то **как**?

Приветствуются даже самые безумные идеи!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько причин, почему это невозможно.

`Marshal.PtrToStructure<Point>` создает копию структуры. Например,
   если вы присвоите результат в локальную переменную, копия
   структуры переместится в стек. После вызова этого метода, вы можете
   изменять память, откуда была скопирована структура, и с вашей копией
   ничего не случиться. Как видно, сама операция безопасна с точки зрения целостности программы.

Под `Marshal.PtrToClass<MyClass>` вы скорее всего подразумеваете разыменование указателя (по аналогии с С++). Сборщик мусора может остановить выполнение целой программы в любом месте, и переместить объекты в памяти. Может случиться что-то такое:

```
IntPtr ptr = получить_указатель_на_экземпляр_класса();
// здесь сборщик мусора остановил потоки, и переместил класс в новое место
MyClass instance = Marshal.PtrToClass<MyClass>(ptr); // ptr указывает непонятно куда
```

`Marshal.PtrToStructure` был придуман для взаимодействия с нативным кодом. `.NET`-классы не могут в обычном понимании существовать в нативном коде, поэтому `PtrToClass` не существует.

Так же есть простой способ при помощи `GCHandle`, который запрещает перемещение объектов в памяти.

Но на C# можно и такое сделать:

```
private static unsafe T PtrToClass<T>(IntPtr ptr)
{
    T temp = default(T);
    TypedReference tr = __makeref(temp);
    Marshal.WriteIntPtr(*(IntPtr*)(&tr), ptr);

    T instance = __refvalue(tr, T);
    return instance;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Value;
}
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    var instance1 = new MyClass { Value = 123 };
    var instance2 = new MyClass { Value = 321 };

    // запрещаем перемещение объектов в памяти
    var gh1 = GCHandle.Alloc(instance1, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var gh2 = GCHandle.Alloc(instance2, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    TypedReference tr1 = __makeref(instance1);
    TypedReference tr2 = __makeref(instance2);

    IntPtr ptr1 = **(IntPtr**)(&tr1);
    IntPtr ptr2 = **(IntPtr**)(&tr2);

    var instance3 = PtrToClass<MyClass>(ptr1);
    var instance4 = PtrToClass<MyClass>(ptr2);
    Console.WriteLine(instance3.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(instance4.Value);

    // разрешаем GC перемещать объекты
    gh1.Free();
    gh2.Free();
}
```

Comment: Понятное дело, что о стабильности тут речи не идёт. Да, имел в виду я именно разыменование в стиле С++. Ну-с, с тем, как получить указатель на структуру (точнее, на ссылку, которой мы оперируем), я извратился и разобрался. Пойду дальше шаманить) За ответ - плюс, но пока подождём, вдруг у кого будет метод такого ненадёжного преобразования)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Я сам озадачился поиском такого метода, пока не получается...

Comment: Ура, я сделал это) Скоро напишу ответ

Comment: @Kir_Antipov у меня тоже получилось, только не получается вынести в отдельный метод

Comment: @Kir_Antipov все получилось, добавил в ответ

Comment: пока я шёл до компьютера, Вы написали как раз то, что я хотел) Спасибо, что поучаствовали в поиске решения)

Comment: А что там с GC? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете превратить указатель в объект по той простой причине что вам неоткуда взять указатель на объект: .net просто не дает такой возможности.

Но если на самом деле вам не нужен именно указатель на объект, а достаточно лишь IntPtr - можно использовать GCHandle.

Создание GCHandle:

```
GCHandle.Alloc(obj).ToIntPtr()
```

Удаление GCHandle (если не сделать - будет утечка памяти!)

```
GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr).Free()
```

Преобразование в объект:

```
GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr).Target
```

Answer (score 1):

> Создание указателя на класс - невозможно (ошибка CS0208)

Создание указателя на класс невозможно напрямую, так как он управляется сборщиком мусора и может быть перемещен в памяти. Однако, класс можно закрепить с помощью Pinned GCHandle и получить указатель на закрепленный объект - но для этого класс должен состоять только из простых типов и иметь атрибут `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` (несмотря на название, его можно применить и к классу).

> А Marshal.PtrToStructure также рассчитан только на структуры

Строго говоря, это не так. Marshal.PtrToStructure работает и c классами, если они удовлетворяют тем же условиям: состоят только из простых типов и имеют атрибут `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`.

Вот пример использования указателей на класс:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    class MyClass
    {
        public int A;            

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return A.ToString();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass my0 = new MyClass { A = 2 };
        MyClass my1 = new MyClass { A = 3 };                       

        //закрепим объекты в памяти
        GCHandle h0 = GCHandle.Alloc(my0, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        GCHandle h1 = GCHandle.Alloc(my1, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        try
        {
            //получим адреса объектов
            IntPtr ptr0 = h0.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            IntPtr ptr1 = h1.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            //убедимся, что адреса реальные и по ним можно считать данные (первое поле класса)
            Console.WriteLine("Значение по ptr0: " + Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr0));
            Console.WriteLine("Значение по ptr1: " + Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr1));

            IntPtr tmp = ptr0;
            ptr0 = ptr1;
            ptr1 = tmp;

            my0 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyClass>(ptr0);
            my1 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyClass>(ptr1);

            Console.WriteLine("my0.A=" + my0);
            Console.WriteLine("my1.A=" + my1);
        }
        finally
        {
            //вернем объекты в управление GC
            h0.Free();
            h1.Free();
        }           

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

В отличие от принятого ответа, здесь используется указатель на сами данные класса, а не на заголовок объекта. Также при вызове Marshal.PtrToStructure создается новая копия объекта, вместо разыменования указателя на существующий объект.

Comment: Мой способ извлекает другой адрес, а именно указатель на заголовок managed объекта. В вашем случае `AddrOfPinnedObject` возвращает указатель на начало блока данных объекта. Но самое главное, ваш код создает копию объекта, а не разыменовывает указатель. Мой код некорректен, но я его исправлю :)